# Understanding functors in OCaml

Tags: module, ocaml, functor

I'm quite stuck with the following functor problem in OCaml. I paste some of the code just to let you understand. Basically

I defined these two modules in `pctl.ml`:

```
module type ProbPA = sig
  include Hashtbl.HashedType  
  val next: t -> (t * float) list
  val print: t -> float -> unit
end

module type M = sig
  type s  
  val set_error: float -> unit
  val check: s -> formula -> bool
  val check_path: s -> path_formula -> float
  val check_suite: s -> suite -> unit
end
```

and the following functor:

```
module Make(P: ProbPA): (M with type s = P.t) = struct
  type s = P.t
  (* implementation *)
end
```

Then to actually use these modules I defined a new module directly in a file called `prism.ml`:

```
type state = value array
type t = state
type value =
  | VBOOL of bool
  | VINT of int
  | VFLOAT of float
  | VUNSET
(* all the functions required *)
```

From a third source (`formulas.ml`) I used the functor with `Prism` module:

```
module PrismPctl = Pctl.Make(Prism)
open PrismPctl
```

And finally from `main.ml`

```
open Formulas.PrismPctl
(* code to prepare the object *)
PrismPctl.check_suite s.sys_state suite (* error here *)
```

and compiles gives the following error

> Error: This expression has type Prism.state = Prism.value array
>          but an expression was expected of type Formulas.PrismPctl.s

From what I can understand there a sort of bad aliasing of the names, they are the same (since `value array` is the type defined as `t` and it's used `M with type s = P.t` in the functor) but the type checker doesn't consider them the same.

I really don't understand where is the problem, can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know enough about OCaml to help, but is it possible that this previous question is a similar problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640510/functors-in-ocaml

Comment: @Gian: it's the same root issue, but if you understand that, you're already well on your way to not needing to ask the question in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(You post non-compilable code. That's a bad idea because it may make it harder for people to help you, and because reducing your problem down to a simple example is sometimes enough to solve it. But I think I see your difficulty anyway.)

Inside `formulas.ml`, Ocaml can see that `PrismPctl.s = Pctl.Make(Prism).t = Prism.t`; the first equality is from the definition of `PrismPctl`, and the second equality is from the signature of `Pctl.Make` (specifically the `with type s = P.t` bit).

If you don't write an `mli` file for `Formulas`, your code should compile. So the problem must be that the `.mli` file you wrote doesn't mention the right equality. You don't show your `.mli` files (you should, they're part of the problem), but presumably you wrote

```
module PrismPctl : Pctl.M
```

That's not enough: when the compiler compiles `main.ml`, it won't know anything about `PrismPctl` that's not specified in `formulas.mli`. You need to specify either

```
module PrismPctl : Pctl.M with type s = Prism.t
```

or, assuming you included `with type s = P.t` in the signature of `Make` in `pctl.mli`

```
module PrismPctl : Pctl.M with type s = Pctl.Make(Prism).s
```

Comment: That's was the problem. I realized it yesterday by looking at the answer give on the question linked by gian inside the comment. I didn't paste my `.mli` file because forgot to do it.. my fault! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem I ran into as well when learning more about these. When you create the functor you expose the signature of the functor, in this case `M`. It contains an abstract type `s`, parameterized by the functor, and anything more specific is not exposed to the outside. Thus, accessing any record element of `s` (as in `sys_state`) will result in a type error, as you've encountered.

The rest looks alright. It is definitely hard to get into using functors properly, but remember that you can only manipulate instances of the type parameterized by the functor through the interface/signature being exposed by the functor.